# Mongo Php Querying from text phrases and their unaccented versions

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I am trying to query some results from a mongo database via php. So i have keywords like Eiffel Tower and è bellissima. However i have data that is also unaccented like "e bellisima" or "E' bellisima".

```
        public function findByKeyword($keyword, $userId, $page = 0)
{

    $connection  = $this->connection;
    $db          = $this->db;
    $collections = $db->selectCollection('database');
    $return      =
        $collections->find(
            array(
                '$text'   => array('$search' => "\"$keyword\""),
                'user_id' => "$userId"
            )
        )
                    ->sort(array('published_at' => -1))
                    ->skip($page)
                    ->limit($this->limit);

    return $return;
}
```

This is what I currently have running but it can only get the ones that match the whole keyword and not the unaccented versions.

```
   '$text'   => array('$search' => "$keyword")
```

using this will also not work because some results have similar keywords like "Tower" in it that does not match the keyword. Any advice on how to proceed with this. I am new to Mongo and Php.